# How to assign a default value to a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

[rooftypecombo-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h44gQ.png)

Hi, I'm new to C# and learning it while developing. I searched almost everywhere but I couldn't find the answer that worked for me.

Problem:
I want to assign the first item in the combo box as a default value. so that the user doesn't have to choose while filling a form( because it will be the most common one).

I tried:

```
if (RoofTypOP.SelectedItem == null)
    RoofTypOP.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5gJy.png)

Comment: For UI-related questions, please add a tag specifying the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...). Probably Winforms in your case.

Comment: What you tried should have worked, although it might be better to test `SelectedIndex < 0`.  Where did you put that code?  I recommend in the constructor, after the call to InitializeComponent(), but in OnLoad can also work well.

Comment: @BenVoigt Omg Thank you, I hadn't put the code after InitializeComponent(). I've been stuck for days because of it. Thanks!

Comment: Although you might be looking for `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` if the user is always supposed to pick one of the existing options and never type in their own.